# PGO instrumented VSTest.Console.exe

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, vstest

I'm trying to run some tests on a DLL that has been instrumented with PGO.  When I run it with the VSTest.Console.exe, I get the following error message:

Error message:
   Failed to set up the execution context to run the test

My goal is to produce some PGC files for the DLL to see if the compiler can produce better code.  BTW, the same thing happens with MSVS.

Does anyone have advice where I may find a PGO instrumented VSTest.Console.exe or another method for what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing this DLL in the same directory as the targeted DLL, allows me to produce PGC files.

pgort140.dll